# Удаление всех символов после указанного

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалить все символы после `/` регуляркой. Подскажите нужную регулярку, пожалуйста.

```
/text123>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "something/text123>"
s.replaceAll("/.*", "");
```

Результатом будет "something".

Comment: а в вопросе ведь речь о «**после** указанного символа», а не «**вместе** с указанным символом».

Comment: Безусловно, но добавить "/" после реплейса никто не запрещает)